# Subtract Two Text/Integer Form Fields in Coldfusion MX7

Tags: forms, coldfusion, subtraction

Pardon me while I probably over-complicate the uber simple, but I'm trying to subtract two text/integer fields in a form. However, I keep getting a 'variable TXTMILEAGE2 is undefined' error. What am I missing/obviously doing wrong?

Code snippit:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="txtmileage1">
<div align="right">Start Mileage:</div></label></td>
<td><cfinput type="text" name="txtmileage1" message="Enter your start mileage."
required="yes" class="box" id="txtmileage1" tabindex="2" validate="integer" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="txtmileage2">
<div align="right">End Mileage:</div></label></td>
<td><cfinput type="text" name="txtmileage2" message="Enter your ending mileage."
required="yes" class="box" id="txtmileage2" tabindex="3" validate="integer"  />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="txtMileage3">
<div align="right">Miles Driven:</div></label></td>
<td><cfset txtmileage3 = txtmileage2 - txtmileage1>
<cfinput type="text" name="txtmileage3" value="#txtmileage3#" disabled="true"
class="box" id="txtmileage3" tabindex="4"/>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Also, this page is being run on a legacy server that hasn't been updated since 2005. Hence the old MX7.

Comment: If the `form` hasn't been submitted then `txtmileage2` doesn't exist. If the `form` has been submitted then you can reference the value as `form.txtmileage2`

Comment: If you want to display that stuff on your form, you'll have to do it with javascript.

Comment: Matt is probably correct about the source of the problem, but .. you forgot to include the actual code causing the "undefined..." error ;-)